# SyncFramework Dynamic Filtering Template Error Creating Select Changes sp

Tags: provisioning, microsoft-sync-framework

I am provisioning a server, Sql 2008 R2, and creating 3 different Provisions, so to speak, with 12 tables in the Scope.  The first provisioning has no parameters , the second and third provisioning with parameters.  On the second and third provisioning I am using templates and adding filters for each table.  I am also specifying a Schema Object.  The filters I am creating are dynamic filters.  When I execute the apply command on the Provisioning for the second and third Provisions, I get the error the _selectchanges stored procedure already exists for that table.  I have set the SetCreateProceduresForAdditionalScopeDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Create). But it is still trying to create the stored procedure with the name of the original stored procedure from the 1st provisioning.

In playing around with it to see what was up I found that for each of the provisions  the insert, update, bulkinsert,etc... stored procedures created for each table are created in the schema I specified but the selectchanges stored procedures for each table were not created in the schema I specified but in the default schema.  Also I found if I did not specify a schema and did all three provisionings, as I describe above, it all worked and the separate selectchanges stored procedures for each table wer created.  I would like to use a different schema though since there are a lot of tables, SPs, and such.

It makes me think when creating the stored procedures for the selectchanges the Sync Framework is checking for the existence of the selectchanges stored procedure for the table with the schema specified in the ObjectSchema parameter but when actually creating the selectchanges stored procedure it is not using the schema specified.

Any ideas on why this would be or if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: on which schema did yo create the scope template?

Comment: I am specifying the schema on all three.  The two templates and the initial provisioning which is not a template.   The schema I am specifying is PowerSync.   Even when I create the initial provisioning, in which I do not use templates, and specify the schema the provisioning is created, with all the tables and stored procedures in the schema I specify except for the select changes stored procedures which are created in the default schema.